# How do I sort a coffeescript Map object by property value?

Tags: sorting, coffeescript

I have a list of `articles` each of which has a simple string array of `Tags`. I count the tag frequency like this:

**Count The Tag Frquency**

```
getTags = (articles) ->
    tags= {}
    for article in articles
        for tag in article.Tags
            tags[tag] = (tags[tag] or 0) + 1
    tags
```

**Example Result**

The `tags` map produced is an object with property names set to the `Tag` name and property values set to the frequency count, like so:

[image]

**Question**

I would like to order this list by the property value (the frequency count), how can I achieve this?

Note: *I am happy to change the counting method if required*

**Edit 1**

Thanks to @LeonidBeschastny I now have working code:

```
getTags = (articles) ->
    tags = {}
    for article in articles
        for tag in article.Tags
            tags[tag] = (tags[tag] or 0) + 1

    tags = do (tags) ->
        keys = Object.keys(tags).sort (a, b) -> tags[b] - tags[a]
        {name, count: tags[name]} for name in keys

    tags
```

You can see that I am having to project the unsorted `tags` map object into a new array of sorted `{name:value}` objects.

This feels like it is too much work and I think maybe the original unsorted object was a mistake. Is there a way to get to the sorted array without going through this intermediate step?

**Edit 2**

Thanks to @hpaulj for doing some time tests and discovering that the code above is actually reasonably efficient compared to other potential solutions, such as a running sorted heap.

I have now put this code into production and it is working well.

Comment: If you'll be satisfied with array of tags, then you may use `Array:sort` method: `Object.keys(tags).sort (a, b) -> tags[a] < tags[b]`.

Comment: I need both the Tag Names and their frequencies for display on the front-end. Perhaps I could use your sorted list as an intermediary to rebuild the `tags` object?

Comment: Yes, you can. Se my answer for details.

Comment: There are data structures, usually implemented as a tree, that maintain a sorted order as you add items (e.g. Python heapq).  So at each step in your initial loop you could pop the `tag`, add 1, and reinsert it.  https://github.com/qiao/heap.js/blob/master/src/heap.coffee is a Coffeescript port of heapq.

Comment: @hpaulj The heap idea looks interesting. Do you have a fiddle of it in action? (to help out the lurkers ;-)

Comment: I have added an answer using a `heap`.

Comment: I did some time tests.  This `count then sort` is considerably faster than using a `heap` to maintain a running sorted list.  I also tried a simpler running sort using `lodash.sortedIndex`, which is somewhat slower than the `heap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may sort your tags using `Array::sort` and then rebuild `tags` object:

```
tags = do (tags) ->
  res = {}
  keys = Object.keys(tags).sort (a, b) -> tags[b] - tags[a]
  for k in keys
    res[k] = tags[k]
  res
```

## Update

As for insertion order, `mu is too short` is right, it's not guaranteed by ECMA specification. `V8` maintains it for literal (non-numerical) keys, but I'm not so sure about other JS engines.

So, the right solution is to use arrays anyway:

```
tags = do (tags) ->
  keys = Object.keys(tags).sort (a, b) -> tags[b] - tags[a]
  {name, count: tags[name]} for name in keys
```

Comment: To correctly sort the `'keys` numerically, descending you need: `keys = Object.keys(tags).sort (a, b) -> tags[b] - tags[a]`

Comment: There's no guarantee that the keys in an object will maintain any particular order. Most JS engines maintain insertion order because a bunch of libraries have stupidly assumed that behavior. You really should be using an array if you care about order.

Comment: @biofractal I also updated my answer according to `mu is too short` comment.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny I used your final, terse syntax. It works well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `heapq`.  This is more complex than simply counting followed by sorting, but may be useful if we need a running sorted count.

Using the Coffeescript translation of Python `heapq`, https://github.com/qiao/heap.js

```
heap = require './heap'
# adapted from 
# http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes
pq = []                         # list of entries arranged in a heap
entry_finder = {}               # mapping of tasks to entries
REMOVED = '<removed-task>'
counter = [0]

remove_task = (task) ->
    # Mark an existing task as REMOVED.  return null if not found.
    entry = entry_finder[task]
    if entry?
        delete entry_finder[task]
        entry[entry.length-1] = REMOVED
    return entry

count_task = (task) ->
    entry = remove_task(task)
    if entry?
         [priority, count, _] = entry
         priority += 1
    else
        counter[0] += 1
        count = counter[0]
        priority = 1
    entry = [priority, count, task]
    entry_finder[task] = entry
    heap.push(pq, entry)

console.log h = ['one','two','one','three','four','two','one']
for task in h
    count_task(task)
console.log entry_finder
console.log pq

alist = heap.nlargest(pq, 10)
for x in alist
    [priority, count, task] = x
    if task != REMOVED
        console.log task, priority, count
```

produces

```
[ 'one', 'two', 'one', 'three', 'four', 'two', 'one' ]
{ three: [ 1, 3, 'three' ],
  four: [ 1, 4, 'four' ],
  two: [ 2, 2, 'two' ],
  one: [ 3, 1, 'one' ] }

[ [ 1, 1, '<removed-task>' ],
  [ 1, 2, '<removed-task>' ],
  [ 2, 1, '<removed-task>' ],
  [ 1, 3, 'three' ],
  [ 1, 4, 'four' ],
  [ 2, 2, 'two' ],
  [ 3, 1, 'one' ] ]

one 3 1
two 2 2
four 1 4
three 1 3
```